# in a specific directories of cpanel can't create file

Tags: cpanel

I have this directory .

http://example.net/webservice/quran/uploads/123456789/

I can't create file in above directory. When I create new file in there the file doesn't show but exist! And when I want to download the file from there give 403 Error.

I can create file in 
http://example.net/webservice/quran

permission of the directory is 744.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issues with the file ownership. Please correct the file ownership and check it. Try to setup ownership user:user for your all files and folder.

If you do not have access to correct the ownership then you will have to contact your hosting provider